# How do I build the dependency graph on ECS?

Tags: entity-component-system

ECS is excellent at decoupling: you split your game logic into multiple pieces, and every system is responsible for dealing with a specific piece. However, I don't know if each system should be aware of the rules of my whole game or if it should only care about its own little domain and be as unaware as possible of the general game rules.

For example, let's say I start building a game where initially entities have position and can move. So I create a `Position` component and whenever I want an entity to move, I assign a `Movement` component to it and let a `MovementSystem` do the job. The movement system will then iterate through all entities with position and movement, do some checking e.g. if movement is inside the entity map's bounds, and calculate the path for the destination. If everything is fine, it'll advance an entity's position a little bit given a delta time. And this process repeats each frame.

Later at some point, I decide to add a `StatusEffects` component which holds the multiple status effects an entity can have such as `Freeze`. Naturally, since an entity is not supposed to be frozen forever, I also add a `StatusEffectSystem` that'll be in charge of updating and removing expired status effects. *Conceptually* speaking, the movement system should know nothing about an entity status effects since all it cares about is movement. But how do I stop an entity from moving when it's frozen?

The naive answer would be to simply remove the `Movement` component whenever a `Freeze` status effect is assigned to an entity. However, that would only stop the ongoing movement, and as long as the player pressed a mouse button to move the entity again, another `Movement` component would be created by the input system thus disregarding the entity's status effects. Of course, we could have an intermediary system for removing `Movement` components of entities with a given status effect so that if any other system created a movement, an status effect remover system would take care of that, and the core update logic would be similar to:

```c
void update(dt) {
    InputSystem.update(dt);
    StatusEffectRemoverSystem.update(dt); // removes Movements if needed
    MovementSystem.update(dt);
    StatusEffectSystem.update(dt);
}
```

However, I think this is bad because if the number of systems is large - and it tends to be -, then it can quickly become unmanageable and bugs can be difficult to spot.

Another approach would be to add a `Movable` component and assign it to entities capable of movement, and whenever we wanted to remove the movability of an entity, we'd remove such a component. The status effect system would then remove the movable component of a frozen entity, and when the frozen status expired, it would add it back. The movement system would also be changed so that it now iterates through entities with position, movement, *and* movable. Everything is fine, right? Not quite.

What would happen if another part of my game logic, maybe a new system, also wanted to add and remove the movability of an entity? Say for example I add an inventory system that allows the player to store their items, but they shouldn't be able to move when they're managing their inventory. Well, I could remove the `Movable` component from the player's entity when they open their inventory, and add it back when they close it. And here's where things get messy. Because if the player happen to have a frozen status (maybe they're opening their inventory to use a potion?), then closing their inventory is all it takes to make them movable again and dismiss their status. Or conversely, if their frozen status ends before they close their inventory, they'll be able to move with their inventory open, which is incorrect behaviour.

Given such considerations, it seems to me that the most straightforward approach for such an issue is to detect if the player has a `Freeze` status in the movement system, in which case the movement would be ignored. Something like:

```c
void MovementSystem.update(dt) {
    foreach (entity with Position and Movement) // forget about "Movable"
    {
        if (entity has StatusEffects and has Freeze)
            continue; // or maybe remove Movement

        ...
    }
}
```

I like it for two reasons. First, it clearly shows the precondition for every movement; no need for such status effect remover system or the like. Secondly, since everything movement-related would be in one place, it's easier to find if something is not behaving as expected. However, it makes the movement system dependant on any changes or feature/component addition I make on my game, which would make each system aware of my whole game rules, which boils down to the question: is this aligned with the ECS pattern? Because I can see how this could be a problem for e.g. a game engine aiming to be extensible.

Answer (score 3):

Make a `Immovable` component that contains a set※1. The idea is that when this set is empty the entity can move.

We can do this by having The `MovementSystem` check, however that would imply iterating over entities that are set to not move. Ideally the `MovementSystem` would not have to do that※2.

---

So, for example, your `Immovable` component has a set of strings, and when the character is frozen, then `StatusEffectSystem` can add the "frozen" string to that set. When the `MovementSystem` checks, it sees it is not empty, and thus it does not move. If you need to debug why... well, you look at the set, and it says "frozen". Eventually the status goes away, and that item can be removed from the set by the `StatusEffectSystem`.

Similarly, the inventory system or whatever other system you need to restrict movement can add and remove items from the set in the `Immovable` component. As long as they only remove items they added, there should be no problem.

This way, you know that a system will not accidentally remove a restriction to movement imposed by another system.

---

※1: A set of what? If you plan on allowing third parties to add system to your game, the `enum` is not an option. Otherwise, an `enum` would work. It is not that system has to add themselves to the `enum`, it is that you add them. If `enum`s are not an option, you can use strings... if conflict is really a problem (you are developing the game, you should know what strings you are using), you can always prefix the strings with the name of the system, assuming you do not have two systems with the same name (which I consider a reasonable assumption) that would solve conflicts. Consider also start the development using strings and switching to `enum`s when the set of systems of your game has been fully decided.

※2: Right, so, we can have `Immovable` and `ImmovableReason`. Where `Immovable` is empty and `ImmovableReason` has the set. Then an intermediary system that runs on changes of `ImmovableReason` and adds or removes `Immovable`. Then `MovementSystem` can query on the absence of `Immovable`. This is, of course, contingent on whatever or not your ECS supports notifications on change of components.

Comment: I considered that option. However, I'd put the set into an `Immovable` component instead of a `Movable` component for the sake of clarity (i.e. it makes no sense a `Movable` entity to have a reason why they can't move). Then the `MovementSystem` would skip `Immovable` entities. But I think this approach is so counter-intuitive that I didn't even bother mention it. That is, a programmer could wonder wtf is this `reason` field in the `Immovable` component, and why such a component exist to begin with. Also, iterating through entities which are not supposed to move seems like a design flaw to me.

Comment: Moreover, even if I decided to do so, I'd have the problem of how to identify the values in the set. Would I use a set of `enum`s or strings? If the former, that means each system I add that wants to use the `Immovable` component would have to add itself to the `enum`; if the latter, then other systems should make sure their string value doesn't conflict with other systems'.

Comment: @SepiaColor sure, call it `Immovable`. About the strings, prefix with the name of the system, unless you have two systems with the same name, that solves that. And, you are right about iterating over them... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @SepiaColor Ideally a system is not aware of the others, so they can change idependently. On that note, if having the `MovementSystem` iterate over all immovable entities and check the reasons is not ok, having the `MovementSystem` check the conditions directly is not particulary better. With that said, requirements triumph design principles. If a design results in an unsable system (e.g. too slow), throw the design. By the way, I would look if you can use code generation for those checks, so you do not forget to update them when you change other systems (in fact, why not pass predicates).

Comment: Alright. So I have two questions: 1) You don't think adding code in the `MovementSystem` as you add new features to your game (as proposed in the end of the original post) is the ECS way to do things, yes? Or, at least, it is not your particular way of working with ECS? Even though we're doing DOD not OOD here, I think the open-closed principle is still relevant and I can see how going down this path would break that.

Comment: 2) One of the benefits of ECS is it reduces cache misses significantly. But using a set would either force you to dynamically allocate memory for storing the `reason`s and cache missing every time you access the field, or using a fixed-size set which may not be what you want. This is a common problem when using containers in a component. Are you okay with that?

Comment: Another thing is you're still iterating through `Immovable` entities, so if you have e.g. 100,000 entities and you command an admin command to stop them all (idk like "/charlesxavier" lmao) and your application runs at 60 Hz, then the `MovementSystem` will be iterating through 60 * 100,000 = 6,000,000 entities per second unnecessarily.

Comment: @SepiaColor on the set, a reasonable initial capacity size should do. You may decide on something like the next power of two after the number of systems. You may log if it needs to grow during tests, and then based on that decide to increse the initial capacity.

Comment: @SepiaColor On the code on your question where you say `if (entity has StatusEffects and has Freeze)` you are still iterating over all of the immovable entities. If your ECS supports running a system when a component changes, you can have a proxy system run once when the `ImmovableRasons` component change, setting the entities `immovable`, and then they can be avoided in the `MovementSystem` query. That is `MovementSystem` would query objects that do not have `immovable`. So, in your "charlesxavier" example, the proxy system  runs once for all those entities, and that's it.

Comment: Yeah. Actually, using `Immovable` is even more performant than using the if condition you mentioned because the if condition is checking for several things. I'm afraid my ECS only support positive queries (so only entities _with_ a component, and not entities _without_), but I think your idea of proxy systems may be doable. I still have mixed feelings about this approach though. Right now, we only have two systems and it's already complicated. What will happen if my game scales to maybe hundreds of systems? Will I have to add an `xReason` for every condition `x` a system may have?

Comment: So, after giving some thought to this, I found the following solution. So you'd have two components, `Movable` and `ImmovableReasons`. Upon entity construction, you assign both. The latter holds an initially-empty set and is never removed. When a system wants to restrict movement, it adds a reason to the set and removes `Movable` from an entity if it has it. When a system wants to make an entity movable again, it removes a reason from the set and checks if the set is empty, in which case the system adds a `Movable` component...

Comment: ...`MovementSystem` then iterates through entities with `Position`, `Movable`, and `Movement`, which makes it as performant as expected. Also, since adding/removing reasons only happen in certain frames, checking for `Movable` won't be a performance hit. My only concern is that having such checks feels like each system is cleaning the mess of another system. Systems are still decoupled in the sense that any system only needs to know that another system may want to restrict movement, not _which_ system. So I suppose this is aligned with ECS, yes?

Comment: @SepiaColor yes, that is good use of ECS and a valid solution of the problem at hand... The advantage of the proxy system, in the problem at hand, is that you do not have to repeat the logic of checking when the set is empty, That would be in a single place.

Comment: @SepiaColor I have also been thinking about the problem and I think `StatusEffectSystem` can be the messier of all systems. Think about status such as "slow" and "haste" (buff and debuff of attributes used by other systems), or stuff like "silence" ("can't cast spells", probably similar to "can't move"), and of course everyones favorite "poison" (damage over time). "sleep" will probably be a problem. Some status effects affects some systems in a way and some other status effects affects another system in another way.

Comment: @SepiaColor I do not know how to generalize the status effects. The closest thing I can think of is a "chemistry engine", a term coined by the Breath of the Wild team. At least there is confort in that other systems will be easier than `StatusEffectSystem`.

Comment: The reason I looked for an alternative to this proxy system is because it's reactive, and that would cause a lot of cache misses. But proxy system or not, this is a dead end because as soon as you check for the existence of a component you'll jump to another memory block, so you're gonna cache miss either way. Btw, cache friendliness is _one_ of the advantages of ECS which apparently can only be achieved with simple computations. Other, perhaps more important ones are flexibility and potential parallelization so I suppose using a reactive system along with ECS is not intrinsically bad.

Comment: Yeah. I think the core of the problem here is that ECS works at its best when used as a pipeline, but the `StatusEffectSystem` puts lots of conditions in many parts of the logic and that doesn't work well with pipelines. In this sense, an `StatusEffectRemoverSystem` would be ideal as it "cut offs" what shouldn't be in the next step of the pipeline, similar to how the GPU works. So if you have e.g. a `Silence` status, you'd remove every `SpellCast` component. But unlike the GPU, game logic tends to be so complex that using such many cut-off/remover systems will drive the game designer crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Entity movement can be influenced by a variety of sources such as local player, network, or even AI so this is why I often find it easier to treat it as state that is mutated across multiple systems.

Lets take this component structure:

```
struct Movement 
{
  // -1/+1 implies move either direction along given axis, 0 implies no movement
  short x, y, z;
}
```

If your entity has a `PlayerComponent`, there would be an associated `PlayerControllerSystem` that would read the input captured by the `InputSystem` and translate that input into actions.  Typically the controller would maintain a map of key<->action mappings that would allow a game to be customized allowing the player to setup keybindings as they wish.

In this example, lets assume that WASD are all mapped to their generally accepted movement bindings of forward, left, back, and right respectively.

It would be the job of the `PlayerControllerSystem` to review the input captured and based on key presses, it would update the `Movement` component's x, y, and z values accordingly to indicate that the player wishes to perform some movement in that direction.

You would then have your `StatusEffectSystem` that checks to determine whether the entity happens to be frozen during this frame.  If the player is frozen, this system would then set the `Movement` component's x, y, z all to 0 for this frame.  If the player is not frozen, no component changes occur.

After all systems that influence movement have had a chance to contribute their interpretation of entity state, your `MovementSystem` then iterates all entities that contain a `Movement` component and based on the values in x, y, and z; that direction gets turned into a movement vector based on interpolation and then gets applied to the entity.

The benefit here is there is no need for any other special component, you avoid cache misses in the `MovementSystem` all together.  You treat each system as either one that simply mutates current state or reacts to current state; e.g. a pipeline.

Also in order to avoid coupling between systems, I mentioned querying input above to see if keys are pressed; this can be handled by moving that state into a component as well.  In my implementation, we have a concept (which Overwatch also uses) called Singleton components.  The idea is that there are certain components that the World maintains a reference to because there is only ever 1 instance and therefore it makes more sense for systems to query that component's state rather than having to know about a system that manages said state.

Comment: I thought about this solution, but this way you're iterating through entities which are not moving too. And as I said in a [comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/how-do-i-build-the-dependency-graph-on-ecs/177059#comment316388_176973), this is a waste of processing power. Depending on how many entities with `Movement` you have in your game and how many of them aren't moving in a given frame, it could be that cache missing all moving entities performed better than cache hitting many of them which aren't moving...

Comment: ...I'm not so sure about you avoiding cache misses "all together" as you said. If your entities are in a map, copying the whole map data to each entity would be an insane waste of memory, so you'd better have a reference to the current map or - if the map is implemented as an entity - the map's entity id, in any case you'd have to jump to the memory address of the map's data causing a cache miss.

Comment: How you choose to store entity data obviously can have an influence on how you may mutate data.  However, I don't understand your reference to map.  Our component storage system allows us to iterate components in a cache friendly way in contiguous memory while also being able to fetch and iterate sibling components in a similar way.  So for movement it boils down to a tight loop which calculates a vector3 of movement and we then apply said movement to the rigid body or non-physics controlled entity.

Comment: In my experience, if your entity system consists of only the entities visible in the area of view around the player, chances are the majority of those that can move are often doing some form of movement frame-to-frame.  There will be some which likely won't because their wander behavior may have entered a pause state for a few seconds, but generally speaking those are considerably fewer than those that are actively moving.

Comment: I'm building a tile-based RPG where maps are comprised of tiles and some tiles are blocked for movement (i.e. entities can't move to those tiles), so `MovementSystem` needs to check if a tile is valid for movement before applying `Movement` to `Position`. Since many entities can be in a same map, it's memory-efficient to store map data somewhere and let each entity have a reference to the map it's currently in instead of storing the whole map data as a component for each entity...

Comment: ...Since in order to get maximum cache efficiency your memory layout should be like `P | MV | MD | P | MV | MD | ...`, where `P` is `Position`, `MV` is `Movement` and `MD` is `MapData`. But that duplicates data and wastes memory.

Comment: You're right wrt the likelihood of movement, and in practice most entities most of the time will be moving, but what about other systems? If you have many systems wasting your processing power with entities that shouldn't be processed, you may end up having a performance hit in each frame update of your application.

Comment: I'm confused why an entity needs a reference to the map or map data at all.  If your entity is physics controlled, the tile that doesn't permit movement would report a collision, you'd check the contacts and not allow the movement.  You might even play a sound when this occurs to give some audio queue.  If the entity is not physics controlled, then your movement system does a `SpatialQuery` to your `SpatialSystem` to determine if the intended movement is permissible.  It's generally acceptable for SystemA to consult SystemB for use cases like this, so storing spatial data separately is good.

Comment: As for performance, there are various ways to handle this.  If your system is only interested in say 10 of the 5000 entities in the scene, you might instead setup a list this system manages based on some event callback system so that the update loop is much faster and iterates over the smaller subset list managed directly by that system.  For use cases where you only ever have 1 instance of a component in the scene, you might find storing those types of components differently can drastically improve performance; see presentation at GDC from Blizzard's Overwatch team about Singleton Components